# Google Static Maps Requests in Console Reporting Too High

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

We are using the Google Static Maps API with a key and signature but the requests showing in the API console are way higher than they should be. We're showing coming up on 2x the number static images served more than page impressions in Analytics and we never have more than one static map per page.

This is an example of a call we make:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=53.7790038,-0.6422849&zoom=12&size=180x130&key=AIzaSyCkWkQAn9EQMYwVvX3ForD9hGLgl3gHfns&markers=color:red%7Clabel:%7C53.7790038,-0.6422849&signature=_Z8LTeim8oNMAvPw_apIKGD2g4w=
```

Does anyone know can the numbers be misreported or can robots calling the image inflate the numbers? Google are starting to charge for this service so the number of calls has suddenly become important.

Comment: It's a good point regarding robots. I would suggest checking this directly with Google support.

Comment: How could we possibly tell? No code posted except one line, no example URL, nothing. Would you feel happy if someone says "Yes, it's the robots!"? You posted the exact same question 4 hours ago and my comment was that you should check the **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** page. Did you do that? I don't think so.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yep, read your somewhat brusque comment and attempted to alter my question accordingly and read the how to ask page. The url goes directly in an img tag to be called by the browser, there is no more code that is relevant and this is similar to what Google have in their own example. 
I would be very happy if someone said "Yes, it's the robots". Knowing it's a known issue would be perfectly satisfactory.